# Preserving transparent colors when converting svg to png

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png

I have an SVG file that contains transparent colors like "#FF000080".

When I convert the SVG to PNG using ImageMagick, the transparent colors are converted to black. (Any colors without an alpha channel, like "#FF0000", are preserved.)

The command I'm running is simply `convert file.svg file.png`.

I have seen a number of questions asking about preserving a transparent background, but haven't found any that address this issue. (My background is not transparent.)

I am using ImageMagick 7.1.1-22 (the latest version from Homebrew, updated this morning) on MacOS 13.2.1, in case that helps.

Comment: What if you edit the SVG to use fill/stroke opacity instead of RGBA colours?

Comment: Post your SVG file. Zip it first before posting

Comment: @fmw42 as far as I know Stack Overflow doesn't allow arbitrary attachments? I tried adding the SVG file as an image to the post but it is not among the allowed image formats.

Comment: @RobertLongson How would I go about doing that? In any case, the SVG file is the output from another program, [verovio](https://www.verovio.org/index.xhtml) so I don't believe I have control over how the colors are represented.

Comment: As I mentioned above, zip the SVG file.  Zip files are permitted on the forum or you can post to some free image hosting web site and put the URL here.

Comment: Well if it were me I'd write an XSLT transform.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) preserves the transparent colors:

`svgexport file.svg file.png`

I'd still like to know if there is a solution using ImageMagick, however.

Comment: Post your SVG file. Zip it first before posting